# Images protected with access token request header

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, cookies, guzzle

I have a webservice that should provide my website with images.
The problem is that the images are protected by a "token" request header.

I use guzzle as client library to call the webservice and fetch the images.

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Service\Client();
$req = $client->get('https://www.customwebservice.be/v1/api/photo/ece1d868.jpg');
$req->addHeader('access_tokenid', 'token123');
$response = $req->send();
$test = ($response->getInfo());
echo '<img src="' . $test['url'] . '">';
```

But no results :S

If i have a cookie set with the same domain as the webservice and the surf to the url it works but i can't set on every user a token cookie right?

Thnx in advance

Comment: I have figured out how i can download the image. But this isn't really what i want to achieve :S

'''' 222         $client = new \Guzzle\Service\Client();
'''' 223         $req = $client->get('https://www.customwebservice.be/v1/api/b4a9c1d52385.jpg');
'''' 224         $req->addHeader('access_tokenid', 'token123');
'''' 225         // $req->setResponseBody('/tmp/test.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how important it is to keep this request token hidden from your users, but if that's the case you could let your application act as a proxy for fetching/serving the images.

To achieve this, you could add a custom route/action which directly passes the image to your client without temporary storing it. Example:

```
public function imageAction($filename)
{
    $response = \GuzzleHttp\get(
        'https://www.customwebservice.be/v1/api/photo/' . $filename,
        array('headers' => array('access_tokenid' => 'token123'))
    );

    return new Response(
        $response->getBody(),
        200,
        array('content-type' => $response->getContentType())
    );
}
```

Your template would look like this:

```
<img src="{{ path('image', {'filename': 'ece1d868.jpg'}) }}" />
```

Be aware that this is a quite low-performing solution, so if your application serves lots of image-heavy pages or has to handle a lot of traffic, you should consider implementing some kind of caching solution.

Comment: Great it works like a charm !!
I have varnish in front of it so it will be cached.

thnx for your help!